# How to manipulate an array of object into a different key and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, reduce

So I have this array:

```
 [{date: "5/7/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},]
```

How to make the array into:

```
[ {"5/6/2021" : 3}, // 3 because there are 3 data with 5/6/2021 date
  {"5/7/2021" : 1}] // 1 because there are 1 data with 5/7/2021 date
```

My Progress. updatedSales is the array name (Edit)

```
const temp = updatedSales.reduce((acc, { name, date }) => {
        acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, dates: new Set(), totalSubmit: 0 };
        acc[name].totalSubmit++;
        acc[name].dates.add(date);
        return acc;
    }, {});

    const result = Object.values(temp).map(({ name, dates, totalSubmit }) => ({ name, uniqueDate: dates.size, totalSubmit }));
```

```js
 const updatedSales=[{date: "5/7/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},]

const temp = updatedSales.reduce((acc, { name, date }) => {
        acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, dates: new Set(), totalSubmit: 0 };
        acc[name].totalSubmit++;
        acc[name].dates.add(date);
        return acc;
    }, {});

    const result = Object.values(temp).map(({ name, dates, totalSubmit }) => ({ name, uniqueDate: dates.size, totalSubmit }));
    
console.log(result)
```

Expectation:

```
[ {"5/6/2021" : 3}, // 3 because there are 3 data with 5/6/2021 date
  {"5/7/2021" : 1}]
```

Right now:

```
[{name: "bob", uniqueDate: 3, totalSubmit: 36},
 {name: "steve", uniqueDate: 12, totalSubmit: 116}]
```

My desired output is the date to be different, not name. So its like "5/6/2021" instead of "bob".

Comment: Please show some code of what you've tried

Comment: So to be clear, updatedSales is the name of the array. This codes was served for another purposes, but this is my progress so far. (Edit: I'll put my progress in the edit)  @koralarts

Comment: It looks like you're basically there. What is your actual question? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking future questions.

Comment: @AndyRay Not yet, I kind of need help on the reduce part.

Comment: What do "need help" and "how to manipulate" mean? What part are you having trouble with specifically? What output are you seeing that doesn't match your expectations and which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: You are currently grouping by `name`. Try replacing `name` in your `.reduce()`-callback function by `date`.  Then you should already get closer to what you want.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Thank you so much for your help, I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

With just a few touches to your script you will get this:

```js
const updatedSales=[{date: "5/7/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},
 {date: "5/6/2021", name: "bob"},]

const temp = updatedSales.reduce((acc, { name, date }) => {
        acc[date] = acc[date] || { date, dates: new Set(), totalSubmit: 0 };
        acc[date].totalSubmit++;
        acc[date].dates.add(date);
        return acc;
    }, {});

    const result = Object.values(temp).map(({ date, dates, totalSubmit }) => ( {[date]: totalSubmit }) );
    
console.log(result)
```

Or, if you really want to, you can reduce it down to a "one-liner":

```
const result = Object.entries(
    updatedSales.reduce((a,{date}) => {
      a[date] = (a[date] || 0) + 1;
      return a;  
    }, {})   ).map(([k,v])=> ( {[k]:v }) );
```

The `new Set()` is not really required here.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, do you mind checking through this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592355/how-to-show-filtered-data-in-javascript-callback-function-react-calendar-month-v? I really appreciate it. Have a good day!